# How to run the loader until the response is fetched from the API in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I am fetching the response from the API. I have also added the loader to the front page in which the response is coming from the API.

I want to run the loader until the response is not fetched from the API.

This is my **tab1.page.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChakapiService } from './../service/chakapi.service';
import { LoadingController, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {
  detu: any;
  newda: any;
  constructor(public chakapi: ChakapiService, public loadingController: LoadingController, public events: Events,
    private storage: Storage) {
    this.detailsfetch('en');
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async detailsfetch($langselect) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      duration: 2200,
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.chakapi.getdetails($langselect).subscribe(data => {
      this.detu = data;
      this.newda = this.detu.data;
    });
    return await loading.onDidDismiss();
  }
}
```

In this I am fetching the response from the API and I have added the loader but the loader is running for a defined time.

I want to run the loader until the response is not fetched from the API.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: remove the `duration` property

Comment: @BearNithi. Okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `duration` property in the loader, and add `loader.dismiss()` inside the subscription of your server call

```
async detailsfetch($langselect) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    this.chakapi.getdetails($langselect).subscribe(data => {
      this.detu = data;
      this.newda = this.detu.data;
      loading.dismiss();
    }, error => { loading.dismiss(); });

  }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add this: error => { loading.dismiss(); }

Comment: Yes, because when there is an error in your server, then also the loader should get closed. Thats what line meant for..

Answer (score 2):

Here is login example with **try catch blocks** with handles both successful and error cases of response. loader waits for response to come from server and stops if response received or some error occurred

```
async login() {
    console.log('login' + this.loginForm.get('username').value);
    try {
      const loading = await this.presentLoading(); // start loader
      const res = await this.authService.login({
        username: this.loginForm.get('username').value,
        password: this.loginForm.get('password').value
      });
      this.loadingController.dismiss();            // stop loader on successfull response
    } catch (error) {
      this.loadingController.dismiss();            // stop loader on some error
      if (error === 0) {
        this.presentToast('Invalid username password');
      } else {
        this.presentToast('Some Error Occured, Please try again');
      }
    }
  }
```

here is the loadinng method

```
  async presentLoading() {
    console.log('starting loading');
     const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      spinner: 'circles',
      keyboardClose: true,
      message: 'Logging you in, Please Wait'
    });
    return await loading.present();
  }
```